# Extruding an SVG with draft for mold making

Tags: extrude, svg

Super new to blender and have tried to find useful tutorials on this problem but they are from 7 years ago and their screen doesn't look anything like mine.
I am working on a project with a school to pour aluminum and plan on using 3d printing to make the master to pull the mold from. We will be making belt buckles or nameplate type things.
These are easy enough to design in tinkercad but that does not allow for a draft angle, which is like a taper to the extrusion, that allows for the mold to come free from the material.
I need to be able to extrude the svg with approx a 5 degree taper.
Can someone help me get this figured out? .

Answer (score 2):

you could give Geometry Nodes modifier a try, it is very simple to extrude a curve and scale the top of it, in Blender 3.1 it's just a few nodes... add some trigonometry to it and you can use angles, I think it's a simple way to automatize the process or part of it

[image: extrude with an angle]

here's a basic setup...

But as posted in the comment this will work fine for simple shapes but no for more complex ones... here's a very quick tutorial on a way you could manually tackle this

1. import svg and maybe adjust resolution
2. right click > convert to mesh
3. go edit mode and select all -press A-
4. press X > Limited Dissolve, use Max Angle: 1°
5. this was to improve topology a bit for next steps, can press Ctrl  T and Alt J to see the changes
6. optional: M > merge by distance and maybe subdivide long edges
7. with all selected press E and then Enter to extrude in place -don't move extrusion-
8. press I and move slowly to inset -to add the draft- and Ctrl move to add thickness

---

and then here's a different node setup in case you still want to try GN and need better draft angles, it's a bit more obscure than previous though... it's a Blender 3.1 file, it expects a planar geometry -your svg is read as a planar mesh by GN- to begin with, will extrude it and try to fatten the base to generate the slope, could be improved yet

[image: extrude with draft angle]

and the 3.1 [blend file to test](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9d3uli3ky9uqddn/extrude%20with%20angle%202.blend?dl=1)

sorry for the convoluted response..! tried to edit it to clarify